# Wordpress CPT UI Plugin - Comments Feed Link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have used `CPT UI` to create a portfolio page on a website. I was using a SEO crawler and found a link on the portfolio page that goes to http://webaddress.com/portfolio/feed, that has a 404 error. It appears on all of the pages, but its only this one that causes an issue.

It appears as a meta link (`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Website » Portfolio Comments Feed" href="http://webaddress.com/portfolio/feed/">`)

All of the other pages have the exact same code, but all go to XML files. I'm not too bothered about keeping the link (not exactly sure what its for). I'd rather have no broken links than have this comment feed.

Any help that anyone can provide will be much appreciated.